# Plot 3d surface map from data frame

Tags: arrays, r, plot, 3d, mesh

I first begin by running the code below to tune a SVM:

```
        tunecontrol <- tune.control(nrepeat=5, sampling = "fix",cross=5, performances=T)
        tune_svm1 <- tune(svm, 
                           Y ~ 1
                           + X
                           , data = data,
                           ranges = list(epsilon = seq(epsilon_start
                                                       ,epsilon_end
                                                       ,(epsilon_end-epsilon_start)/10)
                                         , cost = cost_start*(1:5)
                                         , gamma = seq(gamma_start
                                                       ,gamma_end
                                                       ,(gamma_end - gamma_start)/5))
                           , tunecontrol=tunecontrol)
```

In `tune_svm1$performances` I have 330 observations containing all the values for `epsilon`, `cost`, and `gamma` that I stated in the `ranges` section of the above code as well as another column for the calculated `error`.

I'd like to generate a 3D surface plot for `epsilon`, `cost`, `gamma`, and `error` using three variables as X,Y,Z and the last for color.  I've read on several resources for [plot3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) and [persp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/volcano.pdf) but have had a lot of difficulty implementing.

If I try to follow the examples provided and use `mesh` to generate a mesh plot, I can only mesh together 3 of the 4 variables from `tune_svm1$performances` and saving the separate results for X,Y and Z as shown in the first link is difficult because the mesh is saved as an array, not a matrix.  I've tried to hack a graph using the following code but the visual is nonsensical (probably because the order isn't being preserved by meshing each individually:

```
M1 <- mesh(tune_svm1$performances$epsilon[1:nrow(tune_svm1$performances)]
           ,tune_svm1$performances$cost[1:nrow(tune_svm1$performances)])
M2 <- mesh(tune_svm1$performances$epsilon[1:nrow(tune_svm1$performances)]
           ,tune_svm1$performances$gamma[1:nrow(tune_svm1$performances)])
M3 <- mesh(tune_svm1$performances$epsilon[1:nrow(tune_svm1$performances)]
           ,tune_svm1$performances$error[1:nrow(tune_svm1$performances)])

x <- M1$x ; y <- M1$y ; z <- M2$y ; c <- M3$y

surf3D(x,y,c, colvar = c)
```

What's the best way to approach this?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `rgl` package? I'm thinking of the `plot3d` function, which might help. See: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/rgl.pdf

Comment: Yes @DavidePassaretti I'm trying to use the surf3D or other function from the plot3D package, but I'm having trouble taking my data and formatting it appropriately for surf3D